# cannot be resolved to a variable,where to declare it

Tags: java, android

I'm getting `cant cannot be resolved to a variable`,i know what it's for but i don't know how to fix it.Do i have to declare it somewhere else ? Where ?

I have this :

```
public void calculeaza() {

    totaltest = 0;
    String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];

    for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

        cant[j] = allcant.get(j).getText().toString();
        if (cant[j].matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Ati omis cantitatea de pe pozitia " + (j + 1),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            cant[j] = Float.toString(0);

        }
```

And this :

```
public void salveaza(){
    try {

        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append(cant[1]);
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Nambari That's going to be difficult since the code won't compile!

Comment: Which line shows the error?

Comment: @Simon: what meant was IDE might be showing error, we need line number details etc,.

Comment: The problem is that cant[] is declared in the public void calculeaza and i'm trying to use it in public void salveaza,right ?

Comment: I have to declare it outside the scope ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you declared `cant` in `calculeaza()`, you cannot use it in `salveaza()`. You should declare it outside as an [instance variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) if you are going to share it between methods.

You can learn more about Java Scope here: [Java Programming: 5 - Variable Scope](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2iN3TO5qOQ).

Comment: Could you please give me a quick example on how i could do that ? Thanks !

Comment: @SorinGrecu That's why he posted a link.

Comment: Inside your class, but outside your methods, type `private String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];`. You will need to make sure that `allcant` is also an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use ArrayList instead of String[] and declare it as a class field.

```
public class MyClass{

    private ArrayList<String> cant;  // <---- accessible by all methods in the class.

    public void calculeaza() {

        cant = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int j = 0; j < allcant.size(); j++) {

              cant.add(allcant.get(j).getText().toString());

             if (cant.get(j).matches("")) {
                 Toast.makeText(this,
                      "Ati omis cantitatea de pe pozitia " + (j + 1),
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 cant.get(j) = Float.toString(0);

             }
        ....

     public void salveaza(){ 

        try {

            File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                               new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(cant[1]);
            myOutWriter.close();
            fOut.close();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
    }

 }
```

There are much better ways of doing this but this addresses your question.  Use ArrayList since it is much easier than trying to initialise the array at the class level.

Comment: I now get `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable` at  `cant.get(j) = Float.toString(0);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the array of Strings you call cant `String[] cant = new String[allcant.size()];` in a different method, you can not declare it inside a method.

Declaring a variable inside a method makes it a local method meaning it only exists within that method and can not be seen or used from the outside. Your best choice here is to  declare it as an instance variable.